# Trying to get ListItems from SharePoint with Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to create a small Windows Forms Application that uses data from a SharePoint List.

I've created a Service Reference which gave me all the SOAP-methods I need. It looks similar as to when I insert the WSDL in SoapUI, so I'm assuming the reference is correct as it is.

Afterwards I created a class in my DAL that you can view below:

```
public class Studies
{
    //Constants
    private const string _StudyListGuid = "{DA154DB9-1BE8-4C80-B94E-7EE4B8109905}";
    private const string _StudyViewGuid = "{909C4BED-FB5F-49E5-ABE9-375BA15BBBFF}";

    public List<Study> GetStudies()
    {
        var studyRequest = CreateRequest(); // <-- Fills in the constants in a GetListItemsRequest variable

        var soap = new ListsSoapClient();

        if (soap.ClientCredentials != null)
        {
            //soap.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            //soap.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

            soap.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "username";
            soap.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "pwd";
        }

        //ERROR HAPPENS ON THIS LINE
        var studyResponse = soap.GetListItems(studyRequest.Body.listName, studyRequest.Body.viewName, studyRequest.Body.query,studyRequest.Body.viewFields,studyRequest.Body.rowLimit, studyRequest.Body.queryOptions, studyRequest.Body.webID);

        MessageBox.Show(studyResponse.ToString());

        return TranslateResponse(studyResponse); //<-- Not yet implemented
    }
}
```

And here's my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ListsSoap">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="ListsSoap1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://website.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ListsSoap"
          contract="SharepointService.ListsSoap" name="ListsSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now, for the actual issue. Whenever I run my application and I call the GetStudies() method I get an error saying:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.
```

With an InnerException that says:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Now that all that has been said, I think the problem is that the request I'm sending out isn't authorized (duh). But I thought it would be.. (see code from Studies.cs).

So my first question is: Do I still need to authorize for the request, and if so, how do I do that?

If not, how would I be able to get the ListItems that I want?

I'm sorry for the long post but this is my first time using C# to get SharePoint data and I have no idea what data is actually important and what isn't so I just posted everything (I think). So if anyone has some feedback as to what information is obsolete and which necessary, I'm happy to edit the post.

Kind regards
Gravinco

Comment: You have `if (soap.ClientCredentials != null)`, but what if it *is* null? Don't you want to create the credentials object? Have you debugged and shown that your code goes through the "if" statement and fills out the username/password?

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes I have and yes it does. The 'Check if null' is only there because reSharper suggested it, I still need to refactor that part but I wanted it to work first :-/